# Kid in a car accident goes into a coma, gets transported to a different land, has to fight sister's boyfriend for his life

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for a comic where a kid gets in a car accident with his big sister and her boyfriend and ends up in a coma. The kid gets transported to a different land where he has to fight to escape while the sister's boyfriend is trying to kill him. In the end he kills the boyfriend and wakes up in the hospital where he finds out the boyfriend had died only a few minutes before the boy woke up.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337). When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all the info that could be remembered

Comment: @BjMeers: Do you remember anything about how he fights the boyfriend? Single combat? Magic? Wacky Home Alone traps? Arousing the men of the North to march upon him? Was this a fantasy land? More like reality? Weird reality where it's the world as we know if, but bizarre and improbably things happen? Was this kid elementary school age? High school? College? Same with the sister, how much older were  she and her boyfriend than the kid?

Comment: A boy ending up in a coma after a car accident and being transported to a different land / universe reminds me of _The Dreamwalker's Child_ by Steve Voake, but Sam, the protagonist, doesn't have to fight his sister's boy friend there. But it's a [well known trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AdventuresInComaland) **(warning: link to TVTropes, which can be a serious time sink – proceed at your own risk)**.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163373/name-of-a-fantasy-or-sci-fi-graphic-novel-about-a-boy-in-a-coma

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [Tellos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellos).  It had a lot of hype going in and I enjoyed it but ended sort of quickly after the coma/metastory reveal.  I believe the writer died, so doubtful we'll see more.  Some covers showing the cast:

[image: Issue 1] [image: Prologue]

I don't remember if the evil kid/wizard was involved with a sister or not, but  it's definitely possible.