# Name of a fantasy or sci-fi graphic novel about a boy in a coma

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book that I think I read about five to ten years ago. It was a fantasy graphic novel, in a fairly classic comic book style and kind of a dark premise. The title may have been the name of the world the story took place in. It was about a boy, maybe eleven or twelve, who got into a some sort of car accident or something near his house, and was in a coma. I remember there was a punk rock kid who I think hit him with the car because he hated him, and the punk kid may or may not have also been in a coma. I don't think we found out about that till the end of the book though.

While he's in a coma, the kid creates this world in his head. The character's I remember are (I think): a large guy, kinda beastly, a classically handsome pirate-esque guy, and a woman who looked like Esmeralda from Disney's *Hunchback of Notre Dame*. I can only remember a few details of the plot, but I do remember there was a love scene or something between the main hero and the woman. There may have been a flying ship, there was a chase scene in a town (I think) too.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Kid in a car accident goes into a coma, gets transported to a different land, has to fight sister's boyfriend for his life](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146458/kid-in-a-car-accident-goes-into-a-coma-gets-transported-to-a-different-land-ha) (note, unsolved)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like [Tellos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellos).  It had a lot of hype going in and I enjoyed it but ended sort of quickly after the coma/metastory reveal.  I believe the writer died, so doubtful we'll see more.  Some covers showing the cast:

[image: Issue 1][image: Prologue]

There were definitely flying ships and probably multiple city chases.  Not sure if the romance was between the kid (Jarek) or the "pirate-esque" guy (Hawke).  I can dig my copies out if you need me to find anything specific.

Comment: Oh my god this is! Thank you so much I've been looking for this for-freaking-ever!